# Does Cosmos block a partition while executing a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, concurrency, azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing a sproc that increments a value in a "meta" document for every document the sproc inserts. This will only work if the partition is locked while the sproc executes. Does cosmos lock the partition for writes by other callers or are concurrent writes in the partition allowed while the sproc executes?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos DB has optimistic locking and uses etags for concurrency.

More details can be found at [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control)

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to the docs, `etag` is only necessary in *multi-region writes* and cosmos will magically solve it otherwise. Is that really the case??

Comment: No, that's not the case. Where in the docs does it say that? May need to be updated.

Comment: Second paragraph in that link (about single-write region). Gives you impression that it’s handled magically somehow, vs third paragraph which states you must use etags in multi-region.

Comment: I see what you're looking at. You need to read that paragraph with the one below it as it is describing the difference between single-region write and multi-region write. What is key is you need etag if you have multiple clients simultaneously reading and writing data, even in the same region.  --Thanks.